# What does new() do in `where T: new()?`

Tags: c#, .net, generics

What does the new() do in the code below?

```
public class A<T> where T : B, new()
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is a constraint on the generic parameter of your class, meaning that any type that is passed as the generic type must have a parameterless constructor.

So,

```
public class C : B
{
    public C() {}
}
```

would be a valid type.  You could create a new instance of `A<C>`.

However,

```
public class D : B
{
   public D(int something) {}
}
```

would not satisfy the constraint, and you would not be allowed to create a new instance of `A<D>`.  If you also added a parameterless constructor to D, then it would again be valid.

Comment: Also if you have new() as generic constraint, you can actually instantiate T in your generic function, like so:
T instance = new T();

Without new() as constraint, there's no way to instantiate classes directly (you could still use a static factory, if you have a constraint to a specific class)

Comment: Good point.  You actually get a compile error if you try to do that, which is a nice way of reminding you to add the constraint.

Answer (score 3):

The new() constraint means T has to have a public parameterless constructor. Any calls to T() get turned into calls to various overloads of Activator.CreateInstance(). A more flexible approach (say, if the constructors need arguments, or are internal rather than public) is to use a delegate:

```
public class A<T> where T : B
{
    public void Method(Func<T> ctor)
    {
        T obj = ctor();
        // ....
    }
}

// elsewhere...
public class C : B
{
    public C(object obj) {}  
}

public void DoStuff()
{
    A<C> a = new A<C>();
    object ctorParam = new object();
    a.Method(() => new C(ctorParam));
}
```