# What means where S : new() in c#

Tags: c#, generics

In the following code I do not know what means " where S : new() " part. What is the keyword to find more info in Google ?

```
    public virtual void Print<S, T>() 
        where S : new() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(default(T)); 
        Console.WriteLine(default(S)); 
    }
```

Comment: search for Constraints on Type Parameters . here is link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Duplicate of [C# code confusion of where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5461963), which I found by searching SO for [\[c#\] generic where new](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+generic+where+new). Also, [What does new() do in `where T : new()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1085434) which SO shows in the Related Questions sidebar.

Answer (score 16):

The `new()` constraint means that the particular generic parameter is required to have a default constructor (i. e. a constructor with no parameters).

The purpose of this is typically to allow you to type-safely construct new instances of generic parameter types without resorting to reflection/Activator.CreateInstance.

For example:

```
public T Create<T>() where T : new()
{
    // allowed because of the new() constraint
    return new T();
}
```

For more information, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.

As far as a google search term, I'd try "c# new() constraint".

Comment: The formal name is a _constructor constraint_, so that's something you could also google for. _Constraint_ is the most important word, of course. Note that if `T` happens to be a value type, then `new T();` does not call a real instance constructor; it constructs the same value as does `default(T)`, for value types. For that reason it is not allowed to combine a value type constraint and a constructor constraint, so this is illegal: `where T : struct, new()` (considered redundant). If `T` is a reference type, `default(T)` gives a `null` reference whereas `new T();` calls a real constructor.

Comment: Any value type, including pre-defined integer types and enum types, satisfies the constructor constraint. A reference type satisfies it if and only is it (is non-abstract and) has a **`public`** zero-parameter instance constructor. (Abstract classes _should_ not have `public` constructors.)